# Check input has value on each class element then toggle disabled class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check the values of each input element in my form. It's not working. Can someone help me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

```html
<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thename" name="name[]" type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="date date_of_birth" name="date[]" />
</div>
<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thename" name="name[]" type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" id="stepbirth" class="btn disabled">Next step</a>
```

```js
function formIsInvalid() {
  var flag = false,
    name, date;
  $('.form--group').each(function() {

    name = $(this).find('.thename').val();
    date = $(this).find('.date_of_birth').val().length == 10;
    if (name == "" || date == "") {
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  return flag
}

//Toggle disbaled class
$('.form--group').on('keyup','input', function() {
  //use other static element or document if not works
  $('#stepbirth').toggleClass('disabled', formIsInvalid());
});
```

Comment: `date` is a boolean, hence `date == ""` will never be true

Comment: Use `if (!name || !date)`, and use proper names, i.e. your function should be called `formIsInvalid`, not `checkStatus`.

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: it is very strange to me about this line: date = $(this).find('.date_of_birth').val().length == 10; why is the purpose of == 10 ?

Comment: @Zain:  I misunderstood the request, and I've updated my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.trim()` method to remove all free space at start of value. And check if value is exist.

LIVE EXAMPLE: https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/ZgKqNm

**HTML**

```
<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thename" name="name[]" type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="date date_of_birth" name="date[]" />
</div>
<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thename" name="name[]" type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" id="stepbirth" class="btn disabled">Next step</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#stepbirth.disabled {
  color: #999;
}
```

**JS**

```
function formIsInvalid() {
  var isFormInvalid = false;
  $('.form--group').each(function() {

    var name = $(this).find('.thename').val();
    var date = $(this).find('.date_of_birth').val();

    if (!name.trim() || !date.trim()) {
      isFormInvalid = true;
    }
  });

  return isFormInvalid
}

$('.form--group').on('keyup','input', function() {
  $('#stepbirth').toggleClass('disabled', formIsInvalid());
});
```

Comment: getting this error..
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Comment: see this link: https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/ZgKqNm.  there is no error in this example

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no in-built disabled property for element 'a', you should create a style for that as mentioned below.

```css
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thename" name="name[]" type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="date date_of_birth" name="date[]" />
</div>
<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thename" name="name[]" type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" id="stepbirth" class="btn disabled">Next step</a>

<script>
function formIsInvalid() {
  var flag = false, name, date;
  $('.form--group').each(function() {
    if (flag) return;
    name = $(this).find('.thename').val();
    date = $(this).find('.date_of_birth').val();
    date = date !== undefined && date.length == 10;
    flag = !name || !date;
  });
  return flag
}

//Toggle disbaled class
$('.form--group').on('keyup','input', function() {
  $('#stepbirth').toggleClass('disabled', formIsInvalid());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not working correctly, when filled in all values and remove from the first input field then button remain enabled.

Comment: @Zain Previously it was checking if any of the form--group is valid. Now I updated the code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for updating. It seems to be working here, when i placed this code in js file got this error. 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @Zain That happens if you any of you form--group does not have the specified class. I updated the code for that, as well. :) Hope it does solve you problem.

Comment: That error has gone. Thanks. But still i don't know what is incorrect in my code disabled class not toggled :(

Comment: I invited you to **my_public_chat** room. We can discuss further there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197275/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-v-and-zain).

Answer (score -2):

You can deactivate the button if you find at least one empty field.

Something like

```
var emptyFields = $('.form--group input:text').filter(function() { return this.value.length == 0; });
$(#button).toggleClass('disabled',emptyFields.length > 0);
```

Comment: EDIT : I had understand that you wanted to disable the form group and not the button.